# print japanese with angular

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I have an array of Japanese text like this:

```
[
  "&#28779;&#24433;&#24525;&#32773;",
  "&#8213;&#12490;&#12523;&#12488;&#8213;",
  "&#1053;&#1072;&#1088;&#1091;&#1090;&#1086;"
]
```

I want to print in a scope, but only get the &#codes

the page already have the:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use string literals. What you're using here is a html entities. But it can only be interpreted within html. Javascript will just print the text as is.

Instead, you should use unicode literals instead. The unicode literal will be interpreted by the javascript string parser as it understand that the character isn't ascii.

The char code: 
    28779 -> to hex -> 706B -> to literal -> \u706b

So your string become (note the last line with Cyrillic as a 0 padding in front) :

```
[
  "\u706B\u5F71\u5FCD\u8005",
  "\u2015\u30CA\u30EB\u30C8\u2015",
  "\u041D\u0430\u0440\u0443\u0442\u043E"
]
```

But really why do that? Instead, you can simply output the string directly into utf-8 as if your file is correctly saved in utf-8.

```
[
    "火影忍者",
    "―ナルト―",
    "Наруто"
]
```

It just works.

Comment: I get those array from xhr all the source and compiled js and html files have utf-8. I have even put these array in `<tag lang="ja">` but still does not work, will try this afternoon the decode system you suggest